# Are all cards revealed immediately after all possible betting has concluded in Badugi?

Tags: rules, etiquette, drawing, badugi

Three players A, B and C are in a hand in Badugi in that particular order. With two draws to go, A goes all in for 100, B goes all in for 200. C having 1000 calls the 200. If this were Hold'em, as soon as C calls all three would turn over their cards. But since badugi is a draw game I think this gives too big of an advantage to C.

Which of the following is the correct procedure?
1-a. As soon as C calls, all cards are open. Draws are given face-up.
1-b. As soon as C calls, all cards are open. Draws are given face-down.
2-a. After the conclusion of the next draw all cards are open. Draws are given face-up.
2-b. After the conclusion of the next draw all cards are open. Draws are given face-down.
3. After the conclusion of the last draw all cards are open.
4. After the conclusion of the last draw B who bet or raised last must show first. A and C are allowed to muck.

Answer (score 1):

Stud draw games cards are only revealed at showdown. Showdown only occurs once all draws and betting rounds have concluded.

In your case you mentioned there is no more betting rounds as the players are all-in, but there are drawing rounds. No cards to be face-up yet, as you rightly said it gives C a big advantage.

Based on your procedures listed, 4 is the correct one.